# Transform XML returned from a web request using XLST

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, webrequest

I see several questions that are close to this but none exactly cover it:

- [How to apply an XSLT Stylesheet in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093/how-to-apply-an-xslt-stylesheet-in-c-sharp)
- [XSLT Transform of XML using Xml data from a web form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059348/xslt-transform-of-xml-using-xml-data-from-a-web-form)
- [How to transform an xml structure generated from a request to a web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790515/how-to-transform-an-xml-structure-generated-from-a-request-to-a-web-services)

I can cobble something together from these but I worry I am passing it through too many steps to be efficient.

What I currently have is this, to read XML from a HTTP web request:

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string xml = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

This was before the need to apply an XLST transform was needed. Now I have a (possibly null) `XslCompiledTransform` object.

So I want to add a block like:

```
if(transform != null)
{
  xml = transform.Transform(xml);
}
```

Clearly this isn't possible as written. I see StringReaders and XmlReaders can be created but is it inefficient to get my xml as a string and then push it back into another object? Can I use my `stream` or `streamReader` objects directly to support the same basic flow, but with optional transformation?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd use the `XmlDocument.Load()` function to load the XML from the URL, without using `WebRequest` in this case.

You can pass the `XmlDocument` Straight to `XSLCompiledTransform.Transform()` then.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(url);
if (transform != null)
{
 XmlDocument tempDoc = new XmlDocument();
 using (XmlWriter writer = tempDoc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
 {
  transform.Transform(doc, writer);
 }
 doc = tempDoc;
} //Use your XmlDocument for your transformed output
```

Comment: My issue is there mightn't be a transform and I don't want two quite different code paths. Maybe I'm just not familiar with these classes enough to see how this would hang together... could you provide sample (pseudo is fine) code?